# Incorrect regex group extraction logic in extractGroup

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 6 cells from 'id' column of datatables
Text of that cells are these

```
Supercar 1x01
Supercar 1x02
Supercar 2x01
Supercar 2x02
Supercar 3x01
Supercar 3x02
```

I try to group rows to get 3 cells from 'id' column

```
Supercar 1x01
Supercar 2x01
Supercar 3x01
```

but I obtain only one grouped row and text cell is this

```
Supercar 1x01
```

I don't want to have only one grouped row

I try to to this in this way, this is relevant code:

```
    function extractGroup(text) {
    var match = text.match(/[^\d\s]+/);
    return match ? match[0] : '';
}


function initializeDataTable(data) {
    if (dataTable) {
        dataTable.destroy();
    }
    var tableData = [];
    if (grouped) {
        groupedData = {};
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            
            var groupName = extractGroup(item.id);
            if (!groupedData[groupName]) {
            
                groupedData[groupName] = [];
            }
            groupedData[groupName].push(item);
        });

        // Inserisci un log per verificare groupedData
        console.log("groupedData:", groupedData);

        for (var groupName in groupedData) {
            if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(groupName)) {
                var groupItems = groupedData[groupName];
                var badgeText = groupItems[0].badge;
                var badgeClass = 'badge-' + (badgeText || '').toLowerCase();
                tableData.push({
                    "checkbox": '<input type="checkbox" class="grouped-checkbox">',
                    "id": '<span class="badge ' + badgeClass + '">' + badgeText + '</span> ' + groupItems[0].id,
                    "username": groupItems.map(function(item) {
                        return item.username;
                    }).join('<br>'),
                    "extra": '<button class="downloadBtn">Scarica</button>',
                    "showLinks": groupItems.length > 2
                });
            }
        }

        dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
            "data": tableData,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "checkbox"},
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "username"},
                {"data": "extra"}
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 100, 500],
        });

        // Dopo aver inizializzato la DataTable, chiamare showAllRowsInCell per le celle 'Username'
        if (grouped && groupedData) {
            $('.grouped-mode tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
                var cell = this;
                var rowIndex = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).index();
                var groupName = dataTable.row(rowIndex).data().id.match(/[^\d\s]+/)[0];
                var groupItems = groupedData[groupName];
                if (groupItems) {
                    showAllRowsInCell(cell, groupItems.map(function(item) { return item.username; }).join('<br>'), groupName);
                    // Aggiungi i punti di log qui per verificare i valori
                    console.log("cell:", cell);
                    console.log("content:", groupItems.map(function(item) { return item.username; }).join('<br>'));
                    console.log("groupName:", groupName);
                }
            });
        }

    } else {
        dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
            "data": data,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers[]" value="' + data.id + '" class="individual-checkbox">';
                    },
                    "orderable": false // Rende la colonna non ordinabile
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {

                        var badgeClass = 'badge-' + (data.badge || '').toLowerCase();
                        return '<span class="badge ' + badgeClass + '">' + (data.badge || '') + '</span> ' + data.id;
                    }
                },
                {"data": "username"},
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<button class="downloadBtn">Scarica</button>';

                    },
                    "orderable": false // Rende la colonna non ordinabile
                }
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 100, 500],
        });
```

[THIS](https://pastebin.com/raw/GjmE60RJ) is the javascript complete code to see other errors

The problem is that the current JavaScript code fails to properly group lines based on the first characters that are neither spaces nor numbers within the text. This leads to incorrect grouping of rows.

In detail, the `initializeDataTable` function tries to group data based on specific logic, but it seems that the approach used does not produce the desired result. In particular, the `extractGroup` function is used to extract groups, but it may not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex just match the first part of the string: `Supercar`, because it just look of something that is not a space and a number.

In order to group lines you should match the string including the common part of the number: *1x*, *2x*, *3x*.

You can try the following:

```js
function extractGroup(text) {
    var match = text.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+\s\d+x)/);
    return match ? match[0] : '';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, I fix into this `var match = text.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+\s\d+x)/);`

Comment: Right , sorry I miss the double `/`.